# How to Encode two or more columns in a dataframe using Sk-learn OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, encode

[Here is my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCRU1.png)

I want to encode 2 columns: Lines and Name using sklearn OneHotEncoder and Column Transformer. However, I can only encode one column using this code.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
X = new_df_cl.iloc[:,:-2].values
lines = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [4])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(lines.fit_transform(X))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the tuples in the list of transformers in `ColumnTransformer` is

`(name, transformer, columns)`

where `columns` can be a list of column indices. So if you want to transform the columns at indices 4 and 5, specify columns as `[4, 5]` like this:

```py
ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [4, 5])],  # <-- here
    remainder='passthrough'
)
```